# AddDays() is not incrementing month

Tags: .net, datetime

In my code `AddDays(1)` is working correctly for all days except the last day of the month.

I have a datatable containing data read in from a csv. Each row contains a date as string in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want to add a day this date.
The code below is working for all dates where the day is not the last day of the month, but fails to increment the month otherwise.

Example:

`2019-07-30` correctly increments to `2019-07-31`, but `2019-07-31` increments to `2019-07-01` rather than to `2019-08-01`.

I've tried `Date.Parse`, and tried using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` without success.

MS documentation says

> The AddDays method takes into account leap years and the number of days in a month when performing date arithmetic.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim enUK As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-UK")
For Each row As DataRow In Outs.Select
   Dim Lastdate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(row("EndDate"), "yyyy-mm-dd", enUK) 
   Dim DepDate As Date = Lastdate.AddDays(1)
   row("Date") = DepDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
Next
```

I expect the value of `row("Date")` to be `2019-08-01` for a `row("EndDate")` value of `2019-07-31`, rather than the value I'm getting of `2019-07-01`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `mm` in your format string, which means *minutes* rather than *months*. So you're not parsing the date correctly to start with. You want something like:

```vb
Dim enUK As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-UK")
For Each row As DataRow In Outs.Select
   Dim Lastdate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(row("EndDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd", enUK) 
   Dim DepDate As Date = Lastdate.AddDays(1)
   row("Date") = DepDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", enUK)
Next
```

Note that I've also added the `enUK` argument to `ToString` - otherwise if your current thread culture uses a different calendar system, you could get some very odd results.